# jquery UI looks strange

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been using jquery ui with no problem but just recently the jquery UI elements have started to look strange
for example this button is in firefox 5 the text just isn't sharp and looks bad.

[image: FireFox 5]

And this is that same button in IE9 the text is foating all the way to the top

[image]

I am using jquery 1.6.2

Any thoughts what causes this?
Thanks!

it's not rocket science to do this so not sure how to fix it.

```
....
<input type="button" id="release" value="release">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#release").button();
</script>
....
```

update: i am  using jquery UI 1.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a followup, This issue was specific to the theme I was using(eggplant) once I changed the theme to another(overcast). It looked great again.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably upgrade your version of jQuery UI. That version is pretty old. Not sure if that will fix your issue, but you should be able to keep the existing files and simply replace the UI specific CSS/JS and see if that fixes it.

Comment: How do you know what version of jQuery UI they are using?

Comment: Where exactly does the OP state which version of jQuery-UI is being used?

Comment: i updated it to show jquery ui 1.8.1..looks like the latest is 1.8.14? I will try updating my code and let you know the results.

Comment: I miss read the use of jQuery 1.6.2 to be jQuery UI...my bad.

Comment: It may be new to IE9. FF5 just changed the way % are calculated for some random reason which broke a flexible grid system I was using. I would suggest filing a bug with the jQuery UI team and linking them to this page as well as a jsFiddle page. They are pretty good about dot releases